# Header and text overlapping

Tags: header-footer, tabularx, text

How to avoid overlapping of the header and text?

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[russian]{babel} 
    \usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \rhead{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  X  X  X  }
    LOGO & \small{Класс документа: }    & \small{Id  документа}   & \small{Название документа:}     \\
     &\small{Корректирующие мероприятия}        & \small{1748365}        & \small{САРА 1748365}         \\
    &\small{Тип документа:}    &  & \small{Страница в документе:}  \\ %\№ Версии документа:
    &\small{CAPА}    &   & \small{\thepage}   \\
    \end{tabularx}
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    {\large \textbf{\textsc{Корректирующие и предупреждающие действия (САРА) № 123 }}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{document}` is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add in geometry definition the right place for the header :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm,landscape, headsep=24pt, headheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  X  X  X  }
LOGO & \small{Класс документа: }    & \small{Id  документа}   & \small{Название документа:}     \\
 &\small{Корректирующие мероприятия}        & \small{1748365}        & \small{САРА 1748365}         \\
&\small{Тип документа:}    &  & \small{Страница в документе:}  \\ %\№ Версии документа:
&\small{CAPА}    &   & \small{\thepage}   \\
\end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  {\large \textbf{\textsc{Корректирующие и предупреждающие действия (САРА) № 123 }}}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How to hide a line between header and text?

Comment: Put this _before_ `\begin{document}`  for _header_ : `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`  and for _footer_ :
`\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}`